# Change RootInjector providers in runtime

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Right now my Angular `ErrorHandler` gets passed multiple sub-handlers in it's constructor, e.g.:

```
export const ERROR_HANDLER = new InjectionToken<ErrorHandler[]>('ERROR_HANDLER');

export class ErrorService implements ErrorHandler {
   constructor(
      @Inject(ERROR_HANDLER) subHandlers: ErrorHandler[];
   )
}
```

But sure this doesn't include lazy loaded modules `ERROR_HANDLER`. Is there an elegant way of solving this? E.g.

```
export const ERROR_HANDLER = new InjectionToken<ErrorHandler[]>('ERROR_HANDLER');

export class ErrorService implements ErrorHandler {
   constructor(
      private _injector: Injector
   )

   // Doesn't work since RootInjector never gets modified
   get errorHandlers(): ErrorHandler[] { return this._injector_injector.get(ERROR_HANDLER, [])
}
```

Or just pass the service a method `registerRunetimeHandler(handler: ErrorHandler)` and use it in the lazy modules constructor?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to determine the right injector you wanna use before the initiation and pass it through.

Comment: But since my `ErrorService` is my global error handler (registered in AppModule) it can only rely on the RootInjector. And I guess an already created Injector can never be modified, can it? That's the question.

Comment: You can't change it if its already created, But you said you lazy load the module so you should be able to inject different injectors depends on your needs while you load that modules.

Comment: So the best approach is my edited answer you think?

Comment: Let's keep SO's Q&A format and not put answer in question post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for this but I wouldn't call it elegant.
The solution I'm giving touches on a bit of a different problem but I think it can be modified to suit your case.

#### Problem:

Inject a service that initially is undefined but at some point in the future it gets a value and use that service.

#### Solution:

You can create an injection token but instead of holding a `Class/Service` hold an RxJS `Subject`
(would work with Promise as well)
(ideally `BehaviorSubject<Service>(null)`), and inject that token and subscribe to it and use the service when a non-null value is emitted. At some point in the future (whenever the service is actually provided) you can inject this `Subject` (Promise and emit the service with `next()` (`resolve()`) which will trigger you're before defined logic.

Comment: Guess that's a fair work-around, yes! Thank you very much!